# ExecuteNonQuery return -1 when calling (BEGIN dbms_output.put_line(1);END;) Oracle

Tags: oracle, c#-4.0

ExecuteNonQuery return -1 
when execute commandText (BEGIN dbms_output.put_line(1);END;) in Oracle

When run the same code on Toad it executed successfully

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ExecuteNonQuery returns number of affected rows. For anonymous PL/SQL blocks or DDL returns -1. It's not error.

Comment: How can i check on result ? out parameter ?

Comment: here is simple example http://oradim.blogspot.se/2007/05/odpnet-tip-retrieving-dbmsoutput-text.html. Use DBMS_OUTPUT.GET_LINES or DBMS_OUTPUT.GET_LINE methods.